# Implement all virtual methods but change only some of them

Tags: c++

I want to declare all Base virtual functions in Derived for future reference. I don't mind the default Base behavior but I will probably want to customize some of them later in Derived. What's the best way to do it? So far I'm doing it like this:

```
class Base {
  virtual void fun1(){ /*default behavior*/ };
  virtual void fun2(){ /*default behavior*/ };
  virtual void fun3(){ /*default behavior*/ };
  //more methods here
}

class Derived : public Base {
  virtual void fun1() override { Base::fun1(); /* may be customized later */ };
  virtual void fun2() override { /*specific implementation for derived here*/ };
  virtual void fun3() override { Base::fun3(); /* may be customized later */ };
  //rest of the base virtuals here
}
```

Is it a good practice or is it better to omit unchanged methods?

Comment: I don't think its good practice to have methods with the override specifier that don't actually override anything. Omit them for now, it's no trouble to add them later.

Comment: imho the best would be to concentrate on what you want to override now, methods you only might want to change later you could still override in a `class Derived2 : public Derived`

Comment: I can't think of a practical advantage, only unpractical ones.  Such as having to edit too many classes when you add a method to Base, only to make the code slower.

Comment: Add a virtual destructor in your base class, it is needed if you have virtual methods!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to omit unchanged methods. And it is definitely not good practice to use the `override` keyword *when the behavior of the method is not changing*.

I would suggest using comments if you want to explicitly tell the user that the functions do in fact exist in the base class and they may be modified, but that you aren't changing them for the time being.

---

As another user suggested, you could have an inheritance chain whereby each level of inheritance overrides more methods from the base class. This would be a clear way to do it. Something like this:

```
class Base { /* ... */ };

class Derived1 : public Base { /* override a method from Base */ };

class Derived2 : public Derived1 {/* override a different method from Base */ };
```

Comment: there is overriding actually happening, but other than a tiny overhead it has no effect

Comment: Yes, my mistake. Changed.